# Generating server and client proxys from wsdl files

Tags: c#, wsdl, client-server

I'm encountering a problem generating my client and server code from wsdl.
I've been provided a set of wsdl and xsd files to communicate with an external application.
I need to implement some of them as web services and use the others to generate a proxy to communicate with that external application.
They all use a common header and body structure.
My first though was to generate my proxy server at first and then the client. (with wsdl, using the /serverInterface option to generate the proxy server interfaces).
Problem is that of course, they both define a "Header" and a "Body", so i get errors saying that I've already defined such definitions.
I believe then that I've to generate somehow at the same time the server and the client code, but I don't see how wsdl.exe will allow that.

Anything I'm missing?
I hope I've been clear enough!

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved quite easily... Instead of using the tool, I added the files to VS2008.
It generated automatically the server interface as well as the client code.
Good thing is that this way I'm also sure of the consistency between the generated code and the original files.